# Длина шаблона регулярного выражения

Tags: python

```
import re


def find_all_phones(text):
    result = re.findall(r"\+380\(\d{2}\)\d{3}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{2,3}", text)
   
    return result
```

Как мне задать длину шаблона в 17 символов?

Comment: Наверное нужно будет `\d{1,2}\-\d{2,3}` расписать как альтернативу из двух фиксированных вариантов что-то типа `((\d1-\d3)|(\d2-\d2))`, но я точно не скажу как это записать правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

да, в таком же направлении думал, что и @CrazyElf, получилось что-то типо этого:

```
import re
def find_all_phones(text):
    result=[elem[0] for elem in re.findall(r"(\+380\(\d{2}\)\d{3}\-(\d{1}\-\d{3}|\d{2}\-\d{2}))", text)]
    return result
print(find_all_phones("+380(22)123-12-43hhfjj+380(22)123-1-433urir+380(22)123-13-423"));
```

может вас это устроит. Выдернет шаблоны не более 17 символов.

Comment: Да, что-то я пока про другое думал забыл, что цифры то в скобках надо писать )  И не только это

Comment: а вот если мне нужно чтобы именно result возвращало список уже с готовыми номерами?

Comment: @Гай ну подправил под этот случай.

Answer (score 0):

у меня получилась вот такая неказистая регулярка, но ее еще надо потестировать как следует:

```
r"(?=.{17}(?:[^0-9]|$))(\+380\(\d{2}\)\d{3}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{2,3})"
#------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----подстрока длиной 17 символов после которой идет не цифра, либо конец строки
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
from phonenumbers import parse, PhoneNumberFormat, format_number
from functools import partial

txt = """
Phone: +380676131776  mobile 676790095 home,
Phone: +380 99 053 13 55 work
Home phone 2: (676) 32-61-98
"""
ua_phone_parser = partial(parse, region='UA')

format_num = partial(format_number, num_format=PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)

phone_pat = re.compile(r'[+\d )(-]{6,}')

print(
    *map(
        format_num,
        map(
            ua_phone_parser,
            phone_pat.findall(txt)
        )
    ),
    sep='\n'
)

# +380 67 613 1776
# +380 67 679 0095
# +380 99 053 1355
# +380 67 632 6198
```

```py
# ...
format_num = partial(format_number, num_format=PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL)
# ...
# 067 613 1776
# 067 679 0095
# 099 053 1355
# 067 632 6198
```

```py
# ...
format_num = partial(format_number, num_format=PhoneNumberFormat.E164)
# ...
# +380676131776
# +380676790095
# +380990531355
# +380676326198
```

```py
# ...
format_num = partial(format_number, num_format=PhoneNumberFormat.RFC3966)
# ...
# tel:+380-67-613-1776
# tel:+380-67-679-0095
# tel:+380-99-053-1355
# tel:+380-67-632-6198
```